# Creating Functions with Bash Scripting

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I developed code down below, I would like improve this code for future needs.
So I am thinking that if I use functions, the code could be much better than now it is and It will look organized.

So how I turned to a program or organized code block?

Could you please help me?

**Version:** Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.3 (Maipo)

**(output must be same)**

```
 #!/bin/bash

 hammer host list >| host.list
 cat host.list | grep "RHEL Server" | awk -F'|' '{ print $3}' |  sort > 
 host.modified1
 grp=`sort host.modified1 | uniq -c`
 echo "Linux Versions Grouped by Count" > host.modified1
 echo "" >> host.modified1
 echo "$grp"  >> host.modified1
 echo "" >> host.modified1
 echo "Linux Versions and Hostnames" >> host.modified1
 echo "" >> host.modified1
 cat host.list | grep "RHEL Server" | awk -F'|' '{ print $3"|"$2  }' | sort 
 >> host.modified1
```

output;

```
  Linux Versions Grouped by Count

  8  RHEL Server 6.5  
 21  RHEL Server 6.6  
  1  RHEL Server 6.7  
 10  RHEL Server 6.8  
 39  RHEL Server 6.9  
 19  RHEL Server 7.2  
 34  RHEL Server 7.3  
 30  RHEL Server 7.4  


Linux Versions and Hostnames

RHEL Server 6.5  | xxx.dnsname
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could definitely put this in a function if you wanted. Here's an example where I've also tried to cut down on the processing that you are doing. Since I don't know what the output from `hammer host list` looks like, I have made guesses from what your original code did.

```
do_stuff () {    
    local tmpfile=$(mktemp)
    hammer host list | grep -F 'RHEL Server' >"$tmpfile"

    printf 'Linux Versions Grouped by Count\n\n'
    awk -F '|' '{ c[$3]++ } END { for (h in c) printf("%d\t%s\n", c[h], h) }' "$tmpfile" | sort -k 2

    printf '\n\nLinux Versions and Hostnames\n\n'
    awk -F '|' '{ printf("%s | %s\n", $3, $2) }' "$tmpfile" | sort

    rm -f "$tmpfile"
}

do_stuff >rhel_things.txt
```

The function writes everything out to standard output, and you redirect that output when calling the function.  It uses a temporary file to store the `hammer` output, and deletes this output once it's done with it.

---

If you would want to break it down further:

```
pre_parse () {    
    local tmpfile=$(mktemp)
    hammer host list | grep -F 'RHEL Server' >"$tmpfile"

    printf '%s\n' "$tmpfile"
}

do_group_counts () {
    local infile="$1"

    printf 'Linux Versions Grouped by Count\n\n'
    awk -F '|' '{ c[$3]++ } END { for (h in c) printf("%d\t%s\n", c[h], h) }' "$infile" | sort -k 2
}

do_ver_and_hosts () {
    local infile="$1"

    printf 'Linux Versions and Hostnames\n\n'
    awk -F '|' '{ printf("%s | %s\n", $3, $2) }' "$infile" | sort
}

tmpfile=$( pre_parse )

{
    do_group_counts "$tmfile"
    printf '\n\n'
    do_ver_and_hosts  "$tmpfile"
} >rhel_stuff.out

rm -f "$tmpfile"
```

Comment: Equally, could create the host list first, and then have a function for group by count, followed by a function for version+hostname.

Comment: @steve Example of that added.

Comment: The second example provides a best practice example because functions should be defined as having one purpose and task vs multiple

Comment: second example is the what I would like to do but it only creates rhel_stuff file which is empty.

Comment: @bbenzer Well, then something is wrong.  I don't have your `hammer` output to look at so I can't unfortunately help with debugging. This also means that I've written the code above "blindly" and that there is no guarantee that _exactly_ this code will work for you.

Comment: @bbenzer Standard debugging rules apply: Run the script with `echo` inserted in various places to see that the code is actually executed. Run without redirecting to the result file to see if anything is generated on the terminal. Examine `$tmpfile` (its contents, so don't `rm` it). Run some or all of the `awk` commands manually. Etc.

Comment: @Kusalananda thank you for your help it works.

Answer (score 0):

I think I can do it in a single `awk` program, as below. At first glance it will seem longer than it actually is, because it uses long descriptive variable names and is conscientious about immediately freeing memory when possible.

1. `awk` has powerful native sort functions built in, so there's no need to pipe to an external program.
2. `awk`'s `asort` and `asorti` functions also take an optional third argument, being the *sort method*, which can be things like `@ind_num_asc`, `@ind_num_desc`, `@ind_num_asc`, `@ind_num_desc`, etc. for various ways to sort in ascending or descending order. As usual, see the `man` page.
3. The program is cluttered with `delete` statements in order to be considerate with memory usage, which might become an issue as data sets grow.
4. Shame you didn't give us sample input data to play with. I had a good time coding this, but Lord only knows how close it is to working without input data, so treat the code below as a proof-of-concept that may need work in order to, um, work. The basic take-away is that the most efficient method is probably all internal to a single `awk` program.

`hammer host list \
    | awk -F'|' ' \
        BEGIN {i=0}
        /RHEL Server/ {
          unsorted_count[$3]++
          unsorted_list[i++]=$3"|"$2
          }
        END {
          printf "\nLinux Versions Grouped by Count\n\n"
          i=0
          for (release in unsorted_count)
            count_list[i++]=unsorted_count[release]"\t"release
          delete unsorted_count
          n=asort(count_list,sorted_count)
          delete count_list
          for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            printf "%s\n", sorted_count[i]
          delete sorted_count
          printf "\n\nLinux Versions and Hostnames\n\n"
          i=0
          for (hostname in unsorted_list)
            host_list[i++]=unsorted_list[hostname]" | "hostname
          delete unsorted_list
          n=asort(host_list,sorted_list)
          delete host_list
          for (i=1; i<=n; i++)
            printf "%s\n", sorted_list[i]
     }'`

Comment: The actual processing done by the script is in a sense unimportant in this question. The main point is how to reorganize the code inte distinct operational parts.

Comment: @Kusalananda : Oh well. At this point, the only thing I'l do towards that is to insert a few blank lines in the script in order to visually divide the parts.

Comment: @Kusalananda : [I timed out on editing the prior comment, so this a replaceent] Oh well. A lot of work, and I missed the main point of the question. Still, it should have value for how it deals with the problem, and for how it demonstrates the abilities of `awk`. Also, although it isn't divided up into functions, it's pretty well organized and linear.